# Город Каховка

Tags: топонимика

Интересно было бы узнать происхождение названия города Каховка. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Это-то несложно.

*Каховка. город, р.ц., Херсонская обл., Украина. Возник в 1791 г. как сл. Каховка на землях, пожалованных генералу М. В. Каховскому, участнику русско-турецк. войн второй половины XVIII в., и названа по его фамилии. См. также Новая Каховка.*

Помнится, как-то пыталися докопаться до происхождения самой фамилии Каховский - и потерпели неудачу. Во всяком случае четкого объяснения основы "ках" или "каха" нет.

PS Сразу предупреждаю, многочисленные в Интернете под копирку сделанные "истории" фамилии с упоминанием разного рода процентов носителей генерируется ботом на основании формальных признаков и генератора псевдослучайных чисел.